# VirtualBox: Use real hardware settings for CPU, Hardware Controller etc

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bsod

I'm trying to boot Windows7 off a partition using a openSUSE 11.2 host.

What happens:

1. Turn on the virtual machine
2. Grub shows up like it would on a real reboot. I select windows
3. Windows shows some error about hardware changes. I choose to start windows normally
4. I see the shiny startup animation with the logo
5. BSOD with stop error 0x000007B.

I assume this is because the virtual hardware doesn't match my real hardware. I don't know what to change as I set the CPU count etc accordingly. is there a way for virtualbox to detect and use my real hardware settings (except for ram)?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking Enable IO APIC under system in the VM settings. That might make it work. It may take more work though. The problem you're having is that the HAL that was installed doesn't like the VM. Here's a [link](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows) that describes how to migrate a windows install to a VM. You may also need to do the suggested changes in the Hard Disk Support section.

Try removing the IDE controller from the VirtualBox settings and instead use the SATA. You can do that by right clicking in the controller list. You should be able to add your .vmdk that way.

Comment: I have that enabled. Unfortuantly what I would like to achieve is not having to reinstall windows because I'd like to be able to still boot into windows normally, but being able to launch windows program I have installed from openSUSE 11.2 using virtualbox (adobe premiere, other stuff that doesn't work in WINE).

Comment: Doesn't windows support different hardware profiles or something?

Comment: It does but the HAL is the micro kernel that does all the work of actually loading the rest of the OS. So the HAL has to start before any of the hardware profiles can be used. Also, windows is pretty picky about it's IDE drivers and which controller it was installed on. If you change ide controllers it won't boot without registry tweaking. Since you already have IO APIC enabled then it's probably the IDE driver issue.